# How to check if(Object) in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, control-flow

I have a code in Java:

```
for(Iterator it = c.getArrayList().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Object i = it.next();

    // Here I have an error, i is not a boolean
    if (i) {
        System.out.format("Delete %s%n", i);
        it.remove();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("End");
        break;
    }
}
```

But the `if` clause throws an error. It expects `boolean` but `Object` is given. Java cannot transform types, right?

How do I have to change the type or what do I have to put in the `if` clause to make it work right?

**UPD:**

It is a collection (an ArrayList) of Strings.

```
Object i = it.next();   // I get one element from collection.
if (i) {   // check if it's not the end, if it's not the last element of the collection
```

Comment: What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: What do you want to check it against?

Comment: Traverse the collection removing specific elements. I just want to check if the next element exests then delete it.

Comment: @Green.. And what is that specific element supposed to be? On what basis are you removing it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to check? Please be more specific.

Comment: Do you really want to stop on a `null` value or do you want to print "End" only when it is the end?  I suspect you want to delete null values too.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, I just want to stop when it is the end, when no elements (strings) are in collection

Comment: But you want to keep `null` values in the collection?

Comment: @irrelephant, in fact I don't know, I'm just trying to undestand the Collection Framework, the example is from here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html, Iterators part `static void filter(Collection<?> c) {` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to test whether it's null?

```
if (i != null) {
    System.out.format("Delete %s%n", i);
    it.remove();
}
else {
    System.out.println("End");
    break;
}
```

---

If you're checking the boolean value of `i` and the `ArrayList` is a `List<Boolean>`, then you can use `Iterator<Boolean> it`, but you still have to [be careful](http://ideone.com/ljv5CT) of [null pointer exceptions](http://ideone.com/YxMfH7).

---

**Edit:** If you want to print `End` when all the non-null strings are removed, then you can delete the `else` block and just print `End` after the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Luckly Iterator has a `hasNext()` function.

So you would use:

```
Object i = null;
if(it.hasNext()){
    i = it.next();
}else{
    //done.
}
//Do stuff with i.
```

Comment: He's already doing it in the for statement, that's why I'm not sure if  it's correct what is he doing.

Answer (score 1):

Unclear what do you want to test.

If you want to test, whether object is present, then check for null:

```
if (i==null)
```

If you want to check some property, then cast to specific type

```
if(((MyClass)i).iDontWantLoLive())
```

If the objects are booleans, then cast to boolean:

```
if((Boolean)i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Java is a strongly typed language. If you want/expect boolean values, then do something like this...

```
        List<Boolean> list = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    for (Iterator<Boolean> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        boolean i = it.next();

        if (i) {
            System.out.format("Delete %s%n", i);
            it.remove();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("End");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Otherwise if you're just trying to remove something based on it being null then ('if (i==null)' as others have suggested).

Answer (score 1):

Your output of "End" suggests you want to do this at the end. You can do this instead.

```
List list = c.getArrayList();
for(Object o: list)
    System.out.println("Delete " + o);
list.clear();
System.out.println("End");
```

Note: `format` just returns a String which you are discarding.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very slow way to remove the last element of a list. Instead, use

```
list.remove(list.size() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Java will not automatically coerce types. You will have to manually cast the `Object` to a `Boolean`.